# Capture orientation change event before it happens in Titanium app

Tags: ios, titanium, device, orientation-changes

I'm doing an application in titanium. Different screens are a little complex, because they have a lot of images, views, and webview.

On simulator it works ok, but when I try it on device and I change the orientation of the device, the screen doesn't appear correctly.

For example, if I'm on portrait and I change to landscape, the elements appear like in portrait and then they are relocated to their new position, so you can see the transition.

Is there any way to solve it and don't see the transition?

Is it possible to put something above the view and when the elements are relocated remove it?

The only event I found to manage orientation change is: orientationchange, and if I put a view on the top in this event, I first see elements that aren't in their correct place. Is there any other event fired before the orientation change?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this by creating and opening another window over the top of my current window.  Once I complete the redraw to my hidden window, I'd close out the window I opened to block the view.

My concern would be that this operation may be too fast and the user will just see flickers and not understand what is happening.  The flip side you could put a timer against it so the window shows at least for 1-2 seconds, but then that may be annoying to the user and deter them from changing the orientation.

You could get tricky with this and make the view invisible and then fade it in.  Make sure the window has a background color or it may just show up in black or show something behind it depending on how your developed your project.

```
Ti.Gesture.addEventListener('orientationchange', function(e){
  // ...
  // Cover your current view with another window then remove the window when you complete
  // the redraw.
});
```